# Add Damping to Spring

Tags: python, simulation, game-physics, physics

I have this class for a spring.
I want to add damping to the Spring so it stops after a while, but how should i add it?

My Spring class is:

```
class Spring:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, lenght, k, damping):
        self.particle1 = p1
        self.particle2 = p2

        self.lenght = lenght
        self.k = k
        self.damping = damping

    def update(self):
        force = self.particle2.position.subtract(self.particle1.position)
        x = force.getMagnitude() - self.lenght
        force = force.normalize()
        force.multiplyBy(self.k * x)

        self.particle1.applyForce(force)

        force.x *= -1
        force.y *= -1

        self.particle2.applyForce(force)
```

I also have particle1 and particle2 velocities and accelerations.

Comment: That's a physics question mostly. Damping forces, usually modeled linearly, are in the form of Damping Force = -c * v, where c the damping constant, and v the velocity (v(t))

Comment: Your spring model isn't very good.  The physics aren't correct at all.  Get those right before you add damping.

Comment: @duffymo how so? It looks like it models the force on either end of the spring as the spring constant times the extension of the spring. Sure, they've named the distance between the two "particles" `force` at first, but they do normalize it and multipy it by `k*x`. It seems they do calculate it correctly

Comment: I calculate it correctly!

Comment: So what should I do for the damping?

Comment: Knowing that the damping force is `-c * v` (as mentioned by Thanos), adding that to your currently calculated force should be quite straightforward, no? What have you tried?

Comment: Springs can have any orientation.  They allow force along the axis of the spring.  The endpoints can have 2 dof for a 2D spring or 3 dof for a 3D spring.  The force is a vector in 2D or 3D space.  The spring is represented as a matrix.  I see none of that in your overly simple, incorrect code.

Comment: Dude I have the 2 endpoints and it is 2D and also if you had red the code, My force is vector

Comment: I know but how should i calculate `v` ?

Comment: No, it's not.  But do carry on thinking that you are correct.  You'd need to solve a differential equation for a spring-mass-damper system.  In 1D it's ma + cv + ku = F(t), where a = acceleration, v = velocity, u = displacement, m = mass, c = damping coefficient, k = spring stiffness, F(t) = forcing function.  More points, masses, and springs mean more equations to solve simultaneously.